# Svelte: Binding of value inside an array does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend, svelte

I created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1d88badc7dfb4e0ea12e14af9a178a81?version=3.55.1) to illustrate my issue.
So I have an array with elements and those elements bind there properties to input fileds.
But changing those values does nothing. On log or add all changes get lost.

Thanks in advance

I tried adding a id prop to Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass reference data types (`array` or `object`) - here `arrayItem` for the update to happen, since the update always points to the same reference in memory.

In your example, you are passing primitive types (`number` and `string`) - here `x` and `y`, these have new memory locations when  created, so the update is not done on all locations!

item

```
<script>
    export let arrayItem;
</script>

<div>
    <input bind:value={arrayItem.x}>
    <input bind:value={arrayItem.y}>
</div>
```

parent

```
<script>
    import Item from "./Item.svelte"
    
    let array = [
        {
            x: 1, 
            y: 2
        }
    ];

    function handleAdd() {
        array = [...array, { x: 0, y: 0 }];
    }

    function handleLog() {
        console.log(array);
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each array as arrayItem}
        <Item {arrayItem} />
    {/each}
    <button on:click={handleAdd}>add element to array</button>
    <button on:click={handleLog}>log array</button>
</div>
```

[repl example](https://svelte.dev/repl/8b55679348014722840f1650f2875318?version=3.55.1)